# Parsing HTML Tables with Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Below is the code. I've also attached a photo of the table [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZg1d.png).

The issue I am having is `tr[1]` has the column headers or `th` tags, then `tr[1:40]` has row headers with `th` tags followed by `td` and `th` tags that correspond to the numbers in the table. `td` are normal numbers, but `th` are different because they have a color scheme.

I want to iterate through `tr[1]` to set the colheaders, then set the `th` tags inside the `tr` tags from there on as the row headers. Any information would be much appreciated!

```
import ssl
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

req = Request('https://www.mrci.com/special/corr030.php',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req, context = ctx).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml') # Parse the HTML as a string
table = soup.find_all('table')[2] # Grab the correlation table
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example. No need for SSL and Request, they are not part of your problem. Just paste a multi line string of HTML code with a very small table similar to yours, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026551/python-how-to-insert-a-line-in-a-multi-line-string

Comment: <TR>
  <TH CLASS="colhead" ALIGN=LEFT><a HREF=javascript:popUpL('/ohlc/ym/ym18h.php',660,500) onmouseover="return overlib('Mar 18 E-mini DJIA Index(CBOT)', AUTOSTATUS, WRAP);" onmouseout="nd();">YMH18</a></TH>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TH ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=#80FF80>99</TD>
  <TH ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=#80FF80>98</TD>
  <TH ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=#80FF80>94</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>69</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>-71</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>-80</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>-87</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>80</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT>88</TD>

Comment: I didn't have enough space to include an entire slice of the table. however, I can say that I've figured out how to create a pandas dataframe with the correct headers and number of rows. Now my issue is writing the code to find both 'th' and 'td' tags for each row/column intersection to fill the dataframe.

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    corr_tags = row.find_all('th')

 **I'm not sure how to add 'td' to this prompt as well so it pulls 'td' and 'th' tags consecutively as it iterates from position 1 to 40.

Comment: It is better to try this on a simple example, get it working there. From simple to complex. Take the code you pasted above and great a table with say three rows and four columns, maybe add attributes. Then get your code working with this table. Examine the output, try to figure out how the elements are parsed and where they end up.